# Convert to text Match Phrase only Columns 2 and 5 Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Right now this is changing all of the found "0.059" and "0.0590" I am only looking to either change MatchPhrase of 0.059 or to only change the text in columns 2 and 5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJFx5.png)

```
Sub ConvertTo1_5MM()

    Dim oTable As Table, rng As Range
    Dim nRow As Long
    
    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        With oTable
            Set rng = .Range
            Do
                If rng.Find.Execute("0.059") Then
                    rng.Text = "1.5 MM"
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
                rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Loop
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may get you started:

```
Sub ConvertColumns2and5_To1_5MM()

    Dim oTable As Table, rng As Range
    
    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        Dim ColNumsToSearch As Variant
        ColNumsToSearch = Array(2, 5)
        Dim ColNum As Variant
        Dim TheColumn As Column
        For Each ColNum In ColNumsToSearch
            Set TheColumn = oTable.Columns(ColNum)
            Dim TheCell As Cell
            For Each TheCell In TheColumn.Cells
                Set rng = TheCell.Range
                With rng.Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                    .Text = "0.059>"
                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                    .Replacement.Text = "1.5 MM"
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End With
            Next TheCell
        Next ColNum
    Next
End Sub
```

I modified you code to work only on columns 2 and 5, then loop through the cells in those columns.

To replace `0.059` but not `0.0590` I used `.MatchWildcards = True` in combination with `.Text = "0.059>"` (note the `>` symbol) to search for `0.059` at the end of a word. You may need to tweak the search/replace settings to suit your particular needs.

Comment: There is a debug error @ Set TheColumn = oTable.Columns(ColNum)

Comment: @Mapleleaf Can you post specific details about the error you're seeing?

Comment: When I run the macro in Visual Basic the debugger highlights the line Set TheColumn = oTable.Columns(ColNum)

Comment: @Mapleleaf If I put a table in the document that has less than 5 columns I can reproduce the error you see. How many columns do the tables in your document have? The macro is trying to do a find/replace on *every* table in the active document.

Comment: I have 1 table in the document that has 6 columns

Comment: @Mapleleaf Do you see a message saying what the error is? E.g. "Run-time error '1234'"

Comment: Run-time error '5992': Cannot access individual columns in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths. I added a picture of my table to this post if that helps.

Comment: @Mapleleaf I posted a 2nd answer that takes into account the structure of the table you showed.

Answer (score 0):

When the table has merged cells this should work better:

```
Sub ConvertColumns2and5_To1_5MM()

    Dim oTable As Table
    Const HEADER_ROWS_TO_SKIP As Long = 4
    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        Dim aCell As Cell
        For Each aCell In oTable.Range.Cells
            If aCell.RowIndex > HEADER_ROWS_TO_SKIP Then
                If aCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Or aCell.ColumnIndex = 5 Then
                    Dim rng As Range
                    Set rng = aCell.Range
                    With rng.Find
                        .ClearFormatting
                        .Text = "0.059"
                        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                        .Replacement.Text = "1.5 MM"
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next aCell
    Next oTable
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Would you be able to help me out with another vba script? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68115365/copy-table-rows-from-word-document-to-existing-document-table-specific-cell