# Copy Table Rows From Word Document To Existing Document Table Specific Cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking for a macro that will copy contents from a table in one word document to a table in another existing word document into a specific cell.

Start at row 5 and copy all rows following and paste it to the 5th row in the existing document.

Is this possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knSvC.png)

```
Sub ExtractTable()

    Dim objTable As Word.Table
    Dim tbls As Word.Tables
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim objNewDoc As Document
    Dim objRange As Range

    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set tbls = objDoc.Tables
    Set objNewDoc = Documents.Add("C:\dcam\Setup Sheets\lineup-sheet-template.html")

    For Each objTable In tbls
        Set objRange = objDoc.Range(Start:=objTable.Cell(5, 1).Range.Start, _
            End:=objTable.Cell(25, 1).Range.End)
        objRange.Select
        Selection.Copy
    Next
 
    Set objRange = objNewDoc.Tables(1).Cell(5, 1).Range
    objRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    objRange.Paste
 
End Sub
```

Comment: @xidgel I can't figure out how to set the range of rows 5 through rows.count and when I paste to the existing document it is putting it on the 5th row of the 2nd column instead of the 1st column

Answer (score 0):

If these are empty rows in the destination, why are they there when you could simply use either the FormattedText method or the PasteAppendTable method to add the rows to the destination table?

If there is something below the last row to be replicated, you could simply split the destination table in two and use either of the above methods to both add the rows to the 'top' destination table and join both parts at the split.

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments to your code to indicate where you need to really think about what you are doing and why.

You also need to learn how to use the research tools at your fingertips - particularly the Object Explorer and online help.

```
Sub ExtractTable()

    Dim objTable As Word.Table
    Dim tbls As Word.Tables
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim objNewDoc As Document
    Dim objRange As Range

    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set tbls = objDoc.Tables
    Set objNewDoc = Documents.Add("C:\dcam\Setup Sheets\lineup-sheet-template.html")

    'Why are you looping through all the tables?
    'If you do this only the last one will be available on the clipboard
    For Each objTable In tbls
        'Are you only copying the cells in the first column? Or, does the table only have one column?
'        Set objRange = objDoc.Range(Start:=objTable.Cell(5, 1).Range.Start, _
'            End:=objTable.Cell(25, 1).Range.End)
        Set objRange = objDoc.Range(Start:=objTable.Cell(5, 1).Range.Start, _
            End:=objTable.Cell(objTable.Rows.Count, objTable.Columns.Count).Range.End)
        'Why are you selecting the range when the Range has a Copy method?
'        objRange.Select
'        Selection.Copy
        objRange.Copy
    Next
 
    Set objRange = objNewDoc.Tables(1).Cell(5, 1).Range
    'Why are you collapsing the range to the end?
    'This will cause the paste to be in column 2 as the range is now positioned at the end of cell marker
'    objRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
'    objRange.Paste
    objRange.PasteAppendTable
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to select all the rows from row 5 to the end of the table but I am still getting no results

Comment: @Mapleleaf - as has already been pointed out to you, you should not be trying to select anything. The code above copies from row 5 to the end of the table.

Comment: my first 4 rows have vertically merged cells in it so I think it is messing up the range. I am getting a Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ExtractTable()

    Dim oTable As Word.Table
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim oNewDoc As Document
    Dim oRange As Range

    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set oNewDoc = Documents.Add("C:\dcam\Setup Sheets\lineup-sheet-template.html")
    Set oTable = oDoc.Tables(1)

    If oDoc.Tables.Count >= 1 Then
        With oTable
            Set oRange = oDoc.Range(Start:=oTable.Cell(5, 1).Range.Start, _
                End:=oTable.Cell(oTable.Rows.Count, oTable.Columns.Count).Range.End)
                oRange.Copy
        End With
    End If
 
    Set oRange = oNewDoc.Tables(1).Cell(5, 1).Range
    oRange.PasteAppendTable

End Sub
```